# Firebase not saving data?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, firebase, console.log

I'm trying to scrape a webpage, and save the data to Firebase. I can console.log the data, but I can't get it to save. At first I thought the `tabletojson` function took a second to grab the data, so I decided to put the Firebase part where I save data into a separate function.

When I run this in the terminal, the console.log doesn't appear because something is going wrong with saving the data to Firebase. Any ideas on how to fix this script?

```
var tabletojson = require('tabletojson');
var Firebase = require('firebase')
var url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_sovereign_states#List_of_states';
    tabletojson.convertUrl(url, function(tablesAsJson) {
      var listofSovereignStates = tablesAsJson[0];
      sendToFirebase(listofSovereignStates)
    });

    function sendToFirebase(data) {
        dataRef = new Firebase("https://mikesweather.firebaseio.com/flags")
        dataRef.set(data)
        console.log(data)
    }
```

Comment: What are the `console.log` outputs?

Comment: The console.log doesn't show up, the terminal just stays open

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function sendToFirebase(data) {
    var dataRef = new Firebase("https://mikesweather.firebaseio.com/flags")
    dataRef.set({myData: data})
    console.log(data)
}
```

Per the example below you can see that you need to pass in an object to set:

```
dataRef.set({
  alanisawesome: {
    date_of_birth: "June 23, 1912",
    full_name: "Alan Turing"
  }
});
```

https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/saving-data.html

Edit, after thinking about it, it is possible this is not the solution, let me know if this works...

Comment: I can save the static data, but the data passed in to the sendToFirebase function doesn't work when I try to save data

Comment: log listofSovereignStates before you sendToFireBase and edit the question with that log, lets see what that looks like

Comment: Here's what the console returns when I do that: https://gist.github.com/LAMike310/3f3ccf716cec47374f5eb8639bf6445f , looks like it's a Firebase specific problem right?